# Authlogic and RSpec, errors only running all examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, controller, rspec, authlogic

I have a Profiles Controller that `acts_as_authentic` with AuthLogic and I am trying to test this action:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :except => ['new', 'create']

  def index
    redirect_to(current_user)
  end
end
```

The following example is in a spec file with 18 other pending examples. When autospec runs only this file I get an output like this `19 examples, 0 failures, 18 pending` which says the example is passing, when autospec runs all my specs I get `145 examples, 19 failures` all examples from this spec are failing now.

```
describe ProfilesController, "for logged in user" do
  before(:each) do
    @profile = Factory(:profile)
    controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@profile)
    ApplicationController.stubs(:require_user).returns(true)
  end

  # Index
  context "on get to index" do
    it "should redirect to show user's profile" do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(profile_url(@profile))
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error for every failing spec when autospec runs all the specs:

```
19)
Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'ProfilesController for logged in user on get to index should redirect to show user's profile'
Mock "ProfileSession_1005" received unexpected message :priority_record= with (#<Profile id: nil, first_name: "Test", last_name: "User", email: "user133@example.com", username: "user133", crypted_password: "7aed8331f6d4518483855c07c1b5a507a3f81e5b52019d93d2e...", password_salt: "Nd2gQZjOUA0Ij0IuO6Vp", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, is_admin: nil, persistence_token: "b439ff8bd952964a68a6d00126bafe954e4eab053d81872233e...", perishable_token: "xis77hpS32Wn9pu1PF5R", active: false>)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.5/lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:38:in `find'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.5/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:96:in `get_session_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.5/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:95:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.5/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:95:in `get_session_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb:6:in `result'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:326:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:270:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:301:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:301:in `default_strategy'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.1/lib/factory_girl.rb:20:in `Factory'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_application/spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb:5:
```

What would cause this problem only when all specs are run?

Comment: seems some usage of `mock_model(ProfileSession)` in another spec file that is ran prior to this one was causing the problems

Comment: Can you show the code from your `:profile` factory?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your before filter you could add some steps to log out the current session.